# Web App - Transfer Javascript variable to MySQL (JAVA)

Tags: javascript, java, html, mysql, jsp

Is this possible to transfer a javascript variable (DateTimePicker) so that it can be stored in a MySQL database?

The only way I can think of a way to do it is by converting the javascript variables into a JSON so that it can then be transported to a Java Class (JavaBean) where it can be manipulated and sent to the database. (No PHP, soley Java).

Is this a reliable, good practise method of doing this? As my programming knowledge is still developing.

Comment: Your problem there is that a database cannot store a JavaScript object (which everything in JavaScript is an object). Because Java and sql are not JavaScript their definitions of variables are different the variables thus won't exactly transfer over. However most every JavaScript object has a method called toString which turned it into a plain text string so you could store variables that way but you'd want to make sure that you could still use them afterwards using things like constructors.

Comment: And keep in mind some objects like the JavaScript date object has special toString methods (one for the date object is toDateString) which are more useful then their default counterparts

Comment: Also what do you mean by datetimepicker? Because a date time picker is not a JavaScript variable it's a user interface if you're wanting to save the date object from that date time picker then you would use toDateString or other special methods as described earlier

Comment: @Binvention Okay. I understand the fundamental. But the issue I'm having is literally taking the variable from the JavaScript to the Database. The easiest way of doing it is by connecting the database to the javascript which is not possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Because connecting your database to your JavaScript is a function of your Java server. If your program your server to read a specific type of request and save it to your database then your JavaScript is able to write to your database. But that isn't a question on JavaScript variables

Comment: And if your database is accessible through its own server (like an online hosted database) then storing data should be in its Api.

Comment: @Binvention I've been taught that the database is on the server-side and the JavaScript is on the client-side and it is not recommended that the client-side should not have access to the server. The database is on a local server (glassfish).

Comment: Should they be directly connected without security no. But that is where authentication and secure protocols come in. You program the server to only accept requests that are set up a specific way so that only your web page can submit to it.

Comment: I see. Therefore, If I want to secure the database by creating a JavaBean, what is the most effective method in taking the JavaScript variable (datetime, Strings) to the JavaBean?

Comment: JavaScript making requests to databases happens all the time I mean that's the essence of what online accounts are. JavaScript submits the username password to the server which then stores it to a database

Comment: How you store a date object largely depends on how you want to use it you could use the raw date which is the number of milliseconds since January 1st 1970 or you could use one of the methods like toDateString which returns a date similar to what you're use to seeing

Comment: @Binvention I want store the date which the user has selected from the DateTimePicker into the database. I want to then recall that specific date from the database so that it can be stored in a variable named 'unavailable' which will make the specific date not selectable.

Comment: If it's not going to be seen by people probably use the literal date which can be found using date.value () which is the number of milliseconds one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Spring is a very good framework and https://spring.io/ is very good resource for how-tos/guides.

You have the right idea, you just to complete your thought and try a few things.

Browser -> JavaScript -> Ajax Request -> REST endpoint -> Consume JSON -> Save to database.

Example project https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/tree/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc

Comment: Thank you for the verification. I've looked at the example project that you've provided and it is a bit foreign to me. Are there any simpler 'project/resources' which relate closer to my situation?